# 3-dim Lie algebra with two commutative elements

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\cal g$ be a Lie algebra and let $a,b,c\in \cal g$ be such that $ab=ba$ and $[a,b]=c\not =0$. Let $\mathcal h=span\ \{a,b,c\}$. How to prove that $\mathcal h$ is isomorphic to the strictly upper triangular algebra $\mathcal n(3,F)$?

---

Problem: If $\mathcal h\cong n(3,F)$ then  $\exists a',b',c'\in \mathcal n(3,F)$ with $a'b'=b'a'$ and $[a',b']=c'$ as in $h$ But then $c'$ must equal $0$ whereas $c\in h$ is not $0$?

Comment: Only if the bracket operation is actually given by $ab-ba$. In this case that must not be how the bracket is defined.

Comment: Can we define another Lie bracket on $n(3,F)$. For example $[a,b]=ab$?

Comment: The bracket just has to satisfy the axioms. You could define $[a,b]=0$ for all  $a,b$ in any given vector space to turn it into an abelian Lie algebra.

Comment: I thought the definition of $\mathcal n(n,F)$ is the Lie algebra with the commutator bracket

Comment: That may be true, but $g$ is a different algebra.

Comment: Yes, but if $\phi : g\rightarrow n(3,F)$ we must have $\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(b)\phi(a)$, $[\phi (a),\phi(b)]=0 $

Comment: A Lie algebra homomorphism does not have to preserve any other binary operation, so if $ab=ba$ there's no reason for the same to be true in the image.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain what I mean very well. So the problem is if $h$ and $n(3,F)$ isomorphic. Since in $h$ we have three basis $a,b,c$ with $ab=ba$ and $[a,b]=c\not=0$. Then we must have in $n(3,F)$ a basis $a',b',c'$ with $a'b'=b'a'$ and $[a',b']=c'\not =0$ which is impossible??

Comment: You should put as much relevant information as possible in the post itself. The question is currently not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lie algebra with $[a,b]=c$ is the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}_1$. It has a faithful linear representation given by
$$
    a = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \quad b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \quad c = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix},
$$
see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg-Algebra). Obviously this matrix Lie algebra is given by $\mathfrak{n_3}$, so that $\mathfrak{n_3}\cong \mathfrak{h_1}$.